# Create Authorization based on Roles

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm logging in the user via an AccountController.  The user is authenticated against Active Directory.  A user claim is created with a name attribute with their user name.  I'm using CookieAuthentication.

I want to authorize against an existing user table that will provide the role(s) for authorization.  In ASP.NET MVC I set up a custom authorize attribute but that doesn't seem to be available.  I've seen some very elaborate examples (using authorization policies, etc) for authorization.  They look great but I'm actually doing something rather simple.

I want to be able to decorate the controller or action method with the role(s) required.  For example:

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

Could someone provide a simple example or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Should this role come from AD or app-specific table? Also, have you checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/aspnet/core/security/authorization/roles?view=aspnetcore-3.0

Comment: The role will NOT come from AD, that's just used to authenticate the user.  A separate user table with the user names, application and roles exist in a separate database table.  This is where I'd check what roles, if any, the user has.

Comment: I figured out how to do a basic authentication policy.  My guess is that I should be using the Identity Framework? Can you use this with an existing database table?